# Detect embedded characters in PDF using PdfBox

Tags: pdfbox, embedded-fonts

I am extracting text from a PDF file using PdfBox. When the PDF does not contain any embedded fonts everything works fine. The problem occurs when there are some TrueType embedded fonts. I discovered that in same cases the embedded fonts replace the shape of default characters with some other shapes. For example a char code for 'ï' is used to encode 'ł'. I am aware that I cannot get the real shape of the character without any mapping or OCR. I would like to know which characters might be redefined by the embedded characters. My question is how can I know which characters in the PDF stream are defined by the embedded fonts?